# If $M\subset N \Rightarrow N^{\bot}\subset M^{\bot}$. Seems too easy to be right.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

> If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $M,N$ are subspaces of $H$, such that $M\subset N$ then
> $$N^{\bot}\subset M^{\bot}.$$

Proof:

I think the correct way to show that $N^{\bot}\subset M^{\bot}$, is by taking an element of  $N^{\bot}$ and conclude that it belongs to $M^{\bot}$. So, if $u\in N^{\bot}$, then
$$\langle u,v \rangle = 0,\ \forall v\in N.$$
If $v'\in M$,
$$\langle u,v' \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle = 0,$$ because $v'\in M\subset N.$ Since $v'\in M$ it's arbitrary, follows that $\langle u,v' \rangle = 0, \forall v'\in M,$ therefore $u\in M^{\bot}$.

Note: It's seems pretty simple for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is indeed that simple!

Comment: Then maybe the reverse direction is more difficult to prove ...

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is entirely correct, but the way you write it is a little weird. When you write

$$\langle u, v'\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle,$$

at this point, you have not yet defined what $v$ is. It is better to just write it like so:

> If $v'\in M$, then we know that $v'\in N$ because $M\subset N$. Because $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$ for *all* $v\in N$, it is also true for $v=v'$, which means $\langle u, v'\rangle = 0$.

Or, you can write it even shorter, simply as

> If $v'\in M$, then $v'\in N$ because $M\subset N$. By definition, because $u\in N^\bot$ and $v'\in N$, we have $\langle u, v'\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Thanks man! It's a little weird because I'm not a native I guess. I will take your advice and rewrite this in my notes.

Comment: @JakePark Native or not, it's a good rule of thumb that you only ever write expressions with symbols that are already defined :).